# How to left justify equations in IEEEeqnarray environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, ieeetran

I have an document that use both `IEEEeqnarray` and normal `equation` environment. The `equation` is set to be left justified with

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

However `IEEEeqnarray` is centered. How to make it left justified ?

Comment: I don't think that the IEEE style allows for non centered equations. From what I can see pretty much of what IEEEeqnarray can be done with standard **amsmath** environments. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IEEEtrantools`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) package which provides the `IEEEeqnarray` environment currently does not allow for the `fleqn` class/package option. You can, however, simulate the effect of this option by means of an adequate user-defined glue type:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\IEEEeqnarraydefcolsep{0}{\leftmargini} % any number other than 0 also allowed as glue type

\begin{document}

\noindent
Text\hfill{}Text
\begin{equation}
  x=1
\end{equation}
Text\hfill{}Text
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{0rCl}
  x&=&1
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
Text\hfill{}Text

\end{document}
```

[image: IEEEeqnarray with \leftmargini indent]

This also works if the `amsmath` package is not present.

Note that the `amsmath` package defines a switch `\if@fleqn.` Using this switch you could redefine the `IEEEeqnarray` environment to automatically include the `0` glue type whenever the `fleqn` option is specified.