# Horizontal space in equations with IEEEeqnarray

Tags: ieeetran

I would like to introduce an arbitrary amount of white space to fill a column within an IEEEeqnarray environment, leaving just enough space for the symbol \triangleleft. The command I had in mind (\hfill) does not work.

My concrete problem can be expressed in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{showframe}

% Left alignment for IEEEeqnarray environment
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/how-to-left-justify-equations-in-ieeeeqnarray-environment/25781
\IEEEeqnarraydefcolsep{0}{\leftmargini}

% urls in roman style, theory text in math-similar italics

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some preceding text....
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{0s.s?s.s} %s for left-aligned text
& & LHS-Equation & \\
$\mathcal{R}_2$ & $\equiv$ & $\sqsubseteq$ by justificative .... & \\
& & RHS-Equation &\hfill $\triangleleft$
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
Some following text....
\end{document}
```

Whose compilation produces the following result:

[image]

For the result I want to achieve, I could introduce manual spacing, as in:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{0s.s?s.s} %s for left-aligned text
& & LHS-Equation & \\
$\mathcal{R}_2$ & $\equiv$ & $\sqsubseteq$ by justificative .... & \\
& & RHS-Equation &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $\triangleleft$
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
```

Which results in:

[image]

But this is a very poor solution, if it can be called a solution at all. Any ideas on how to automatically shift the \triangleleft to the right-hand side of the page?

Comment: What is the problem with `align` with `\tag{\triangleleft}`?

Answer (score 1):

While revising "How to Typeset Equations in LATEX" by Stefan M. Moser I came across strechable spaces in the IEEEeqnarray. It seems it solves the problem I was having before.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{showframe}

% Left alignment for IEEEeqnarray environment
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/how-to-left-justify-equations-in-ieeeeqnarray-environment/25781
\IEEEeqnarraydefcolsep{0}{\leftmargini}

% urls in roman style, theory text in math-similar italics

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some preceding text....
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{0s.s?s+x*} %s for left-aligned text
& & LHS-Equation & \\
$\mathcal{R}_2$ & $\equiv$ & $\sqsubseteq$ by justificative .... & \\
& & RHS-Equation & $\triangleleft$
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
Some following text....
\end{document}
```