# Indent all flalign* environments

Tags: flalign

I have a rather long paper with multiple calculations done in flalign* environments. I would like for all of those calculations to be indented 15pt from the left margin. I hope that this makes sense, and would like to know if there is there any simple way to do this to all of the calculations in the paper?

Comment: Do you real have 3 alignment columns? Or is it only to have a column aligned at the left margin?

Comment: I have 3 columns i.e. x &= y + 1 &\\

Comment: The only solution  is nesting  `flalign*` in the `adjustwidth` environment (from `changepage`). You also can try `fleqn` from `nccmath`, but use `align*` or `alignat*`.

Comment: The \adjustwidth method worked, but it added spacing between the text above the calculations and the first line of the calculations that I'd rather not have. Is there any way to fix this? {\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} didn't seem to help

Comment: I'll take a look at the code. However, do you want the third column aligned at the right margin? If you don't, the `fleqn` environment method is much simpler (it works somewhat like `subequations`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the flalign* environment altogether. I used IEEEeqnarrays, and I used \mathindent along with the methods described here [How to left justify equations in IEEEeqnarray environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/how-to-left-justify-equations-in-ieeeeqnarray-environment) 
to achieve what I wanted.